# Set signed cookie information in a Rails integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, integration-testing

There is a lot of information out there, but none of it seems up-to-date.  With a Rails 4 integration test, how do you set a signed cookie?

For example, assuming I load the session :user_id from the cookie, this is the way I would expect to test it, but no joy:

```
cookies.signed[:user_id] = 1
get '/'
assert session[:user_id] = 1
```